# git show equivalent in Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

What would be the equivalent of `git show` in Mercurial ? I am mostly after the diff between given changeset and its parent, not necessarily the changeset metadata.

Ideally expressed as alias in `hgrc`.

Answer (score 4):

To see the diff for a commit, simply use `hg diff -c REV`. You can also specify the first and last revision by using `-r` twice, e.g. `hg diff -r REV^ -r REV`.

As an alias, just use:

```
[alias]
show = diff -c
```

(Note that show is already a Mercurial command, so you may want to pick a different name.)

Alternatively, `hg log -p` or `hg export` can also be used if you need to see the commit metadata as well, but `hg diff -c` allows you to use the regular diff options, e.g. to ignore whitespace.

For a revision range, you can use the `::` revset operator. `hg diff -r 'REV^::REV'` works as well (see `hg help revsets` for more information on how to express non-trivial revision sets).

Comment: `hg help show` describes it as the `hg config` command, so it's really just a built-in alias for `hg config`. The actual alias is `showconfig` so even with an alias defined, `hg showconfig` still runs the `showconfig` command.

Comment: The `hg show` command is part of the recently added `show` extension (part of core Mercurial, not an actual extension that you have to install) and not the same as `hg showconfig`.

Comment: Aha, I guess I need to upgrade hg versions. (Mine is 5.1.2.)

Comment: It should already be in there, but as with other backward-compatibility breaking changes, you need to enable it first.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: since `hg show` is now a core-provided extension, it's probably wise to pick another name.  See also [Reimer Behrends' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284855/1256452) and the comments there.

---

I have a tiny script I use.  It is not terribly clever but it lets you use a `git show <rev>` or `git show` (to see `HEAD` / `.`) as `hg show`:

```
[alias]
show = !hg-show "$@"
```

where `hg-show` is:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

# hg-show - helper script for "hg show"

case $# in
0) $HG log -pv -r .;;
1) $HG log -pv -r "$1";;
*) $HG log -pv "$@";;
esac
```

It should be easy enough to put the entire script into the alias, if you prefer that.  I had planned to make the script fancier someday, but have not been using Mercurial for several years now.  (I first wrote the above script itself probably sometime around 2013.)

Comment: Ah, I did not know `hg log` has the -p option. Was trying something like `hg diff -r X^1:X` where `X` is the revision number.

Comment: You can (as in Reimer Behrends' answer) use `hg diff` with two `-r` options, which is what I use (well, used to use) for diffing particular revs. For my `show` I wanted to see the log message too, a la `git show`, though.